# Discord.js (v.13) error: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

A few months ago, I had a problem with this code too, but I fixed the problem after some solutions found here. But, since yesterday, the bot is having the same issue as before, but I don't understand why, I don't even have changed something in the code, but it keeps having the same error.

It's a bot showing the weather for a specified location when you ask. It works for some locations, but otherwise, it has this error:

```
/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/959726696393748519/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's useful to say that, but there is some time between when I run the command, and when the error message is displayed.

Here is the full code:

`index.js`:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
var weather = require('weather-js');
const { Client, GuildMember, Message } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json")
const client = new Client({
    intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILDS"]
});
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const prefix = "!";

client.on("ready", () => {
...

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    let command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
    if (command === "weather") {
        client.commands.get("weather").execute(message, args, Discord, weather)
      }
    });
    

client.login(config.token);
```

`weather.js` :

```
var weather = require('weather-js');

const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'weather',
    description: "Used to get the weather of a place",
    execute(message, args, Discord, weather) {
  
      const city = args[0]
  
      weather.find({search: args.join(" "), degreeType: "C"}, function(error, result){
  
        if (error) return message.channel.send(error)
        if (!city) return message.channel.send("You must specify a location please!")
  
        if (result === undefined || result.length === 0) return message.channel.send("**Invalid location**")
  
        let current = result[0].current
        let location = result[0].location
  
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`Weather forecast for ${current.observationpoint || "NO DATA"}`)
.setDescription(`${current.skytext || "NO DATA"}`) //Using a direct call can cause an error.
.setThumbnail(current.imageUrl) //If this part is the culprit let me know
.setColor("RANDOM")
.setTimestamp()
.addField("Temperature: ", `${current.temperature || "NO DATA"} °C`, true)
.addField("Wind Speed: ", `${current.winddisplay || "NO DATA"}`, true)
.addField("Humidity: ", `${current.humidity  || "NO DATA"}%`, true)
.addField("Timezone: ", `UTC${location.timezone  || "NO DATA"}`, true)
  
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});
  
      })
  
    }
  }
```

I was searching on some websites about how I could solve the "Cannot send an empty message" error, but nothing worked for me. I also tried to type another code using `weather-js`, but it didn't worked either.

Comment: Just curious, if you're going to import `weather` and `Discord` anyway in the `weather.js` file, why unnecessarily list them as parameters and pass them?

Comment: If you mean why is there the "var weather" in the index.js file as welll as in the weather.js, it's because I followed step by step a tutorial to add the weather command to a bot. As far as I remember, in the tutorial, that's how the code was, so I just added this to the index.js. It has to be done because there's a line in the index.js that requires "var weather" to be declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `error` in `if (error) return message.channel.send(error)` is an object and you can only send a string as the message content.

Change it to `error.message` (that's a string) and it should work as expected:

```js
if (error) return message.channel.send(error.message)
```

Comment: I tried this, and I no longer have the problem Cannot send an empty message, thank you! But now, instead of sending me the message embed with the city weather I requested, my botsends a message, like ```ETIMEDOUT``` or ```request failed (503)```.

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `args.join(' ')` is? It would be a good idea to check the devtools' network tab to check the URL the request is sent to and if there is any error there.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what do you mean by checking the value of ```args.join(" ")```? 
As far as I know, the website used for the weather forecast is msn.com, but everything is working well on the website...

Comment: One possible error could be that `search: args.join(" ")`. So you should console.log  `args.join(" ")`

Comment: I tried adding the console.log(args.join(" ")), and it logged what I typed after my "!weather" command, so I think all is well on that side, but after, my bot still sends ```request failed (503)```.

Comment: Is it a valid place? Because if I try _London_ for example, it works. Error is `null`, and the result is an object with the details. But if I type _London, UK_, there is the same error 503 as you mentioned. Pretty strange but maybe it's just the way `weather-js` or msn is handling errors. It hasn't been updated in a pretty long time.

Comment: I guess the problem is from weather-js, because it happened suddenly... The location I'm requesting is a location that was working well before, but if I type it with the ZIP code after, it works. Otherwise, the other locations that were working before are not working anymore, so I don't think the problem comes from the code... 
In any case, thank you very much for your help and the time you took to help me!